# Trying to retrieve data from appended list with button

Tags: html, list, cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list that looks like this ,[Appended List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6whsc.png)

and this is the HTML code:

```
     <!-- Two Line List with secondary info and action -->

  <ul id = "contactList" class="demo-list-two mdl-list">
    <li class="mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--two-line">
      <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
        <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
        <span id="contactId" class="contactId1">Name</span>
        <span class="contactInformation mdl-list__item-sub-title">Information</span>
      </span><div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
        <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-info"></span>
        <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action" href="#"><button id="viewContact" onclick="viewContact1()" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
  View
</button></a>
      </span>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

this is the javascript code:

```
    function show(){
  $("#contactList li").remove();

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user != null) {
user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
    var email = profile.email;
    var emailsplit = email.split(".")
    var userid = emailsplit[0]
    var contact = emailsplit[1]
var test = document.getElementById("test");
test.innerHTML = userid;

var firebaseRef1 = firebase.database().ref("Ecard/business cards" + userid).orderByKey();


firebaseRef1.once('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var id = childSnapshot.key;
  var Information = childSnapshot.val();
  // ...

    // ...


  $("#contactList").append("<li class='mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--two-line'><span class='mdl-list__item-primary-content'><i class='material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar'>person</i><span class='contactId1' id='contactId'>" + id + "</span><span class='contactInformation mdl-list__item-sub-title'>" + Information + "</span></span><div class='mdl-layout-spacer'></div><span class='mdl-list__item-secondary-content'><span class='mdl-list__item-secondary-info'></span><a class='mdl-list__item-secondary-action' href='#viewContact'><button id='viewContact' onclick='viewContact1()' class='mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored'>View</button></a></span></li>");

  });
});
});
}
});
// ...
```

I would like to program the view button to relay/get the data from the "contactInformation" and "contactId" for its specific list item. So far I implemented this:

```
function viewContact1(){
  var id =  document.getElementById("contactId").innerHTML;

    alert(id);
```

But it only returns from the first List item instead of the list item its on. How do i fix this?

ps. The information from the database has random generated keys and is added and removed by the user of the application, so its never a set amount of data.

after i click the view in the second list item: 
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHVzf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because as you create new contacts you will keep creating 'contactId' id. Since you have lots of them the method will get the first of them.
Instead of appending as you did consider creating your View and Button dynamicaly(DOM Nodes) and attach listener after it:

```
var ul = document.getElementById("contactList");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.className = "mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--two-line"
//Create you spans etc. I am skipping to button for detailed info look HTML DOM Nodes
var button = document.createElement("button")
button.append(document.createTextNode("View"))
button.addEvenetListener('click', function(){
  //This id is the id that you have declared
  alert(id);

});
li.append(button);
ul.append(li)
```

By that way you are creating different instances